# Iterating hash of arrays to create an array of array

Tags: ruby

Suppose I have a hash

```
@attribute_type = {
  typeA: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
  typeB: ['1', '2', '3'],
  typeC: ['9', '8', '7']
}
```

I want to iterate over the values so I can create an array having all distinct possible combinations of the three arrays, for example:

```
['a', '1', '9'], ['a', '1', '8'], ['a', '1', '7'], ['a', '2', '9'], ...
```

Is this possible?

Comment: The answer you selected offers the possible combinations of `type[:A]` in combination with types B and C. However your question states *"all possible combinations"* in which case `h.values.flatten.combination(3).to_a` is potentially more correct depending on if you meant distinct values or permutations. Right now based on the chosen answer `["a","b","c"]` is not considered a valid "combination" so *"all"* might be misleading

Comment: I meant all distinct possible combinations. I'll edit the question to reflect this. Thank you.

Comment: So would `["a", "b", 1]` be considered valid? If so the selected answer does not cover this. Nor does your example to be honest

Comment: No I just want all distinct possible combinations from the three arrays. I don't know how to word it. Can you please help me with that? What I want is the combination of 1 value per set inside the array, so like {typeA * typeB * typeC}, but I want the values for each combination.

Comment: Your description seems sufficient based on the answer you selected I was just looking clarification to make sure.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
h = { :typeA=>['a','b','c'], :typeB=>['1','2','3'], :typeC=>['9','8','7'] }

first, *rest = h.values
  #=> [["a", "b", "c"], ["1", "2", "3"], ["9", "8", "7"]]
first.product(*rest)
  #=> [["a", "1", "9"], ["a", "1", "8"], ["a", "1", "7"],
  #    ["a", "2", "9"], ["a", "2", "8"], ["a", "2", "7"],
  #    ["a", "3", "9"], ["a", "3", "8"], ["a", "3", "7"],
  #    ["b", "1", "9"], ["b", "1", "8"], ["b", "1", "7"],
  #    ["b", "2", "9"], ["b", "2", "8"], ["b", "2", "7"],
  #    ["b", "3", "9"], ["b", "3", "8"], ["b", "3", "7"],
  #    ["c", "1", "9"], ["c", "1", "8"], ["c", "1", "7"],
  #    ["c", "2", "9"], ["c", "2", "8"], ["c", "2", "7"],
  #    ["c", "3", "9"], ["c", "3", "8"], ["c", "3", "7"]]
```

See [Array#product](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-product).

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, what does `first, *rest = h.values` mean? I don't get the first part, and the comma as well.

Comment: Suppose `arr = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]`. Let's try it: `first, *rest = arr; first #=> [1,2,3]; rest #=> [[4,5,6], [7,8,9]]`. The asterisk is called a *splat*. [This article](https://endofline.wordpress.com/2011/01/21/the-strange-ruby-splat/) provides a good explanation, especially the section *Array Destruction*.

Comment: I think your autocorrect meant to let you say *Destructuring* in that comment.

Comment: @IBG you can also target the values explicitly, i.e. `h[:typeA].product(h[:typeB], h[:typeC])`

Answer (score 1):

My 2 cents.

Pretty the same as Cary Swoveland, but just one line:

```
h.values.first.product(*h.values.drop(1))
```